# why boost implement BOOST_CURRENT_FUNCTION in a function

Tags: c++, boost, macros

boost implements a macro BOOST_CURRENT_FUNCTION in its [current_function.hpp](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_65_0/boost/current_function.hpp)
, the macro is to provide the full name of the function, for exception throw, logging etc.

What is interesting is that the macro is implemented inside a function.

What's the special reason of doing so?

```
....

namespace boost
{

    namespace detail
    {

        inline void current_function_helper()
        {

            #if defined( BOOST_DISABLE_CURRENT_FUNCTION )

                # define BOOST_CURRENT_FUNCTION "(unknown)"

            #elif ...

            #elif defined(__FUNCSIG__)

                # define BOOST_CURRENT_FUNCTION __FUNCSIG__

            #elif ....

            #else

                # define BOOST_CURRENT_FUNCTION "(unknown)"

            #endif

        }

    } // namespace detail

} // namespace boost

....
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Upon looking at the full implementation one sees that it makes use of several compiler specific "function signature" macros. Those macros are of course only valid *inside a function*.

The test `#elif defined(__FUNCSIG__)` is going to fail at file scope. And so must appear inside a function. Here the helper is introduced to supply a function scope for this check.

The [documentation on MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b0084kay.aspx) confirms this:

> - **__FUNCSIG__** Defined as a string literal that contains the signature of the enclosing function. The macro is defined only within
>     a function.

Comment: Thanks. Typical case where the developer failed to put a useful comment in the source code.